# It Type of Hacking

Tags: multiple-devices, google-account

[image: Screen Shot] in google play when i am installing something it is showing two devices associated with my gmail id.How can i remove another device?I think Its some kind of hacking.

Answer (score 2):

If a device you no longer use is listed (or if you don't recognize the device), you can remove it from your account. To remove devices from your account:

1. Use your phone's browser to go to [myaccount.google.com](https://myaccount.google.com).
2. In the "Sign-in & security" section, touch **[Device activity & notification](https://myaccount.google.com/security?pli=1#activity)**.
3. In the "Recently used devices" section, touch **[Review devices](https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity)**.
4. Touch the device you want to remove > **Remove**.

Source: [Google Support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6264236?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to the above answer:

If you fear about security of your playstore Gmail account 
you can go for [Google two step verification](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/)

Everytime you sign in from any device or anywhere you will be asked for OTP.
It gives another layer of security to your account.